# defining Page URLs in one configuration file YII

Tags: php, url, yii, yii-url-manager

is there anyway to defining Page URLs in one configuration file and make it more user friendlier. 
For example

```
/index.php/randomuser/default/index => randomuser
/index.php/randomuser/default/view => randomuserview
/index.php/useroftheday/default/index => useroftheday
/index.php/useroftheday/default/view => userofthedayview
```

Answer (score 0):

just configure in your **Url Manager** in config file like this -

```
'urlManager'=>array(
    'urlFormat'=>'path',
    'showScriptName'=>false,
    'rules'=>array(
        'randomuser'=> 'randomuser/default/index',
        'randomuserview'=> 'randomuser/default/view',
        'useroftheday'=> 'useroftheday/default/index',
        'userofthedayview'=> 'useroftheday/default/view'
    )
)
```

your new url will be - `http://domain.com/randomuser`